StringApp installed on Cytoscape, But does not added to IMPORT/Network from Public Database
I have different versions of Cytoscape in different PCs. one is 3.10.1 and the other is 3.10.2. for both I installed StringApp but in 3.10.2, It is not added to "import/network from public DB". can anybody tell me what's wrong with this version?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you have any program screenshots that demonstrate this error? It seems like there's missing contextual information in the question you've asked, but I'm not familiar enough with Cytoscape to know what would help for answering your question.

I just tested this on a Mac running 3.10.2 and StringApp 2.1.1 and the String queries show up in both the File->Import->Network from Public Databases... and the network search bar.  You may want to check and see if you are getting some kind of import error on startup.
